# UIActivityIndicator not showing

Tags: swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I have the following code and I can't work out why my Activity Indicator is not showing. 
I am not sure why it won't show. I basically have the start and stop animating functions wrapped around code code that connects to an API and returns JSON Data. Depending on the connection speed the transaction will varying in time. I want this Activity Indicator to show while this is occurring. Does it have to do with the DispatchQueue

```
        self.activityIndicatorView = ActivityIndicatorView(title: "Converting...", center:     self.view.center)
        self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicatorView.getViewActivityIndicator())

        self.activityIndicatorView.startSpinner()
        UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        //Run the fetchConversion regardless
        //Codes is run here to get a JSON response removed to clarity but this can take some time depending on internet connection speeds. 

        UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        self.activityIndicatorView.stopSpinner()
```

calls this function in Activity Indicator View

```
class ActivityIndicatorView
{
var view: UIView!

var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

var title: String!

init(title: String, center: CGPoint, width: CGFloat = 200.0, height: CGFloat = 50.0)
{
    self.title = title

    let x = center.x - width/2.0
    let y = center.y - height/2.0

    self.view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))
    self.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0) //  UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 204.0/255.0, blue: 51.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5)
    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    self.activityIndicator.color = UIColor.black
    self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = false

    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
    titleLabel.text = title
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

    self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
    self.view.addSubview(titleLabel)
}

func getViewActivityIndicator() -> UIView
{
    return self.view
}

func startSpinner()
{
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
}

func stopSpinner()
{
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

}

Any Help much appreciated

Comment: There is neither *code that connects to an API* nor `DispatchQueue`. The given code starts and stops the indicator too fast for your eyes.

Comment: I have commented that part out. Not relevant to showing the ActivityIndicator. Assume that code runs for 10 seconds.

Comment: The code is relevant unless it runs synchronously. And why do you call `begin/endIgnoringInteractionEvents` twice respectively?

Comment: It can be start and stop super fast can you add sleep or wait function before start and stop?

Comment: understood. The code that runs the transaction calls a function in another class instance.